# What is the 'html-in-font' page called?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Simple enough question.

What is the 'aspx' or 'ascx' page called? I need the correct term to properly search google or define a question on here that should be fairly simple to answer, but I'm sure I'm not using the correct vocabulary so my question and google searches are not netting me anything.

To be clear, the 'code-behind' page is written in c#, I want to know what the page that would contain HTML and <% %> tags would be called.

I'm asking because another question of mine was answered very poorly and then ignored by everyone else and I think it's because I'm not sure how to name that page correctly. Going round the houses slightly but once I got my terms correct I can move to the next stage of solving my problem.

Comment: Most people just call it Markup, or the Markup view...

Comment: I think of it as asp.net is client side, and the c# is server side

Comment: @theedam Worth noting that both the markup + server controls are processed by the asp.net runtime **server side** where HTML is emitted from the controls/code and sent to the client machine as raw HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always refered to the page as the "markup" page is that what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

aspx page is actually the webform page where you define the markup like '<%' or html code. To keep things simple, we get the facility of having a seperate 'code behind' where we can write c# code. However, in aspx (webform) we can also write c# code, i am sure you must be aware of that.

ASCX page is nothing just a User Control page.

I hope i have answered your question. Just for information of whoever reads this post, ASPX is the enhanced version of a classic ASP page whose file extension used to be 'asp'. So when microsoft introduced ASP.NET they needed something that would reflect the advancement. So they named their page ASP+. As the windows doesn't allow a + sign as a file extension, they tilted the '+' sign and made it 'x'. This is how ASPX was derived.

Comment: thanks for the long answer, if I could mark two answers I'd include your, but AdamWhite got straight to the point.

Comment: Its ok, not a problem. But atleast you could have voted my answer up. :-)